# Apply discount coupon code on first recurring payment in paypal (paypal-subscriptions)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal (PHP) for recurring payment. It is working fine , but now i wants my user to get discount if they subscribe to my plans.

It is something like this, Plan actual cost is $20, if user subscribe to this plan , he should pay only $15,as $5 is given discount (only first time, after that next billing should be of $20).

can anyone help me how to do it in paypal.

Answer (score 3):

I understand, Paypal currently is not supporting coupons or any kind of discounts on their `/v1/billing/subscriptions` or `/v1/billing/plans` endpoint.
You can manage yourself by creating Plan B (copy of Plan A but with a discount on price) and displaying that plan on the checkout. Then deactivate and activate other plan.